# Нажатие по дочернему элементу

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, с такой ситуацией:
есть `DIV` с классом "`cls`", на jQuery у меня есть событие `click` по этому блоку. В этом блоке есть картинка и получается когда я кликаю по картинке, срабатывает событие `click`, которое относится ко всему блоку "`cls`". Как можно исключить нажатие по картинке?

Comment: в оброботчике клика проверяйтя является ли `target` картинкой или нет

Comment: спасибо получилось, уже в этом направление начал копать!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
 $('div.cls').click(function() {
     if (event.target.nodeName != 'IMG') {
           //код
     }
 });
```

Comment: Тогда уже:

    $('div.cls').click(function(e) {
        if (e.target.nodeName != 'IMG') {
           //код
        }
    });

Answer (score 4):

e.stopPropagation() - предотвращает распостранение евента который висит на родителях

```
$('.cls').('click', function(e) { 
   alert('cls clicked');
}).on('click','img', function(e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('cls img clicked');   
});
```

демо тут http://jsfiddle.net/M34Ez/

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
$('div.cls > img').on('click', function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation(); //На всякий случай
   e.stopImmediatePropagation(); //Тоже на всякий случай
   return false; // И чтоб точно не сработало :)
});
```

Comment: Напомнило [это](http://govnokod.ru/11723)

Comment: Типа, а вдруг [внезапно](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE) сработает )))

Comment: Какие все умные, просто пипец..

А то, что мой ответ вполне рабочий никого не волнует

Comment: ваш ответ "слишком" рабочий

Comment: @Photon - вы вообще понимаете что делает каждая из строчек? Можете объяснить зачем они? :)

Comment: ссылки класс.. hahah